# Github API - How can I see the Diff of a File in the Repo?

Tags: github

I just wanted to see the diff of a file in the Repo - for example, want to see the difference of the file between July 1st and July 15th.

I was trying to do below -

1. get the commit ID of the file which was committed on July 1st 0:00
2. get the commit ID  of the file which was committed on July 15th 0:00
3. use [compare-two-commits API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#compare-two-commits) to compare above #1 commit and #2 commit

Actually above doesn't work, if those commits contains over 300 files changes due to the limitation of [compare-two-commits API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#compare-two-commits).
Since our Repo contains more than 30K files, it happens very often that one commit contains >300 files changes.

I tried to search this in [Github API reference](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference), but I couldn't find.

So if there is the way to get the diff of one file in a Repo (let's say between now and half month ago), that would be really great.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing it via GitHub API vs git?

Comment: If you want a GitHub-specific answer, use just the one tag (i.e., remove the Git tag).

Comment: Oh I see. I will remove git tag

Answer (score 0):

```
git log -p --since=01.07.2021 --before=16.07.2021 <filename>
```

this works for me, it gives you a history of all commits in the given date range

or alternative, if you want to compare two commits directly with each other you can use

```
git diff <commit-id> <commit-id> -- <filename>
```

Comment: But the OP is asking about using the GitHub API and not `git`.

Comment: Thank you. Actually there are number of Repos we need to look into, and there will be many users who cannot clone everything. So if it could be done by APIs, that would be good.